# Does Solr Suggester support infix search?

Tags: autocomplete, solr, prefix, infix-notation

The [wiki page of the Solr Suggester component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) does not mention how the provided field is searched? Is it a prefix only, or is there also an infix search possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It supported.
Edit your solrconfig.xml, go to searchComponent element, change value of "lookupImpl" from org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory(As shown in  [wiki page of the Solr Suggester component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) example, but it can be another like FuzzyLookupFactory etc...) to AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory.

It's need to be very similar to this:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">mySuggester</str>
 <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">yourSearchFieldName</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">yourSearchFieldType(String, text-general)</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" 
              startup="lazy" >
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="suggest">true</str>
  <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

**Don't forget to restart your solr after changes.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do "infix" or n-gram style auto-suggest activity against an indexed field that has an [N-Gram Tokenizer](http://search.lucidimagination.com/search/document/CDRG_ch05_5.5.5?q=gram) in it's analysis chain.

Comment: Yes, I know. But is it possible to use N-Gram Tokenizer with Suggester somehow, or use a text field for the Suggester component?! I don't thinks so.